# How do you loop through multiple elements in a xml using beautiful soup4

Tags: python, xml, beautifulsoup

What I want to do is to extract elements from a xml object and list individual attributes
(Real world example, I backed up sms texts from my phone as xml and want to rewrite them as a csv)

I have been looking online for help to do this and found beautiful soup.  It seems to do exactly what I want it to do.  Using examples online I can extract information from the first element.  But I can’t for the life of me figure out how to progress beyond the first tag in the group.  From what I can tell, the code below should give me:

5555555555 -  Aug 30, 2019 11:10:09 PM

6666666666 -  Aug 30, 2019 11:10:09 PM

7777777777 -  Sep 01, 2019 07:50:09 AM

but instead I get the below error

allsms = soup.findall('sms')
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable

I feel like I am missing a step.  Can anyone here help me find what I am doing wrong

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' standalone='yes' ?>

 <sms address="555555555" type="1" subject="null" body="hello world" t sub_id="-1" readable_date="Aug 30, 2019 11:10:09 PM" contact_name="Mr. X" />
 <sms address="6666666666" type="2" subject="null" body="world says hello" sub_id="-1" readable_date="Aug 30, 2019 11:10:09 PM" contact_name="Mrs. Y" /> 
 <sms address="7777777777" type="1" subject="null" body="relatable fact: carrots are not all orange" sub_id="-1" readable_date="Sep 01, 2019 07:50:09 AM" contact_name="Mr. Z" />  

################
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
with open('texts.xml', 'r') as f:
data = f.read()

soup = BeautifulSoup(data, "xml")
allsms = soup.findall('sms')
for i in allsms:
sms=soup.find('sms')
address=sms.get('address')
realDate=sms.get('readable_date')
print(address + ' - ' + realDate)
```

Comment: `sms=soup.find('sms')` is always going to be the first sms element because you're querying the original soup object over and over... you want to reference `i` inside the loop (or better yet... rename `i` to `sms` and then drop your `sms=soup.find('sms')` line...

Comment: it's find_all or findAll but not findall

Comment: @diggusbickus `findAll` has been deprecated for *ages*... just not removed as it'd likely break too many things at the moment... so yeah... I'd recommend `find_all`

Comment: @Jon Clements - thank you, that worked!

Comment: what is this **t** --> `body="hello world" t sub_id="-1"` . It makes the XML invalid

Answer (score 0):

Removing the extra **t** in the first `sms` element, wrapping the xml with root and using python builtin xml lib

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

xml = '''<r>
   <sms address="555555555" type="1" subject="null" body="hello world" sub_id="-1" readable_date="Aug 30, 2019 11:10:09 PM" contact_name="Mr. X" />
   <sms address="6666666666" type="2" subject="null" body="world says hello" sub_id="-1" readable_date="Aug 30, 2019 11:10:09 PM" contact_name="Mrs. Y" />
   <sms address="7777777777" type="1" subject="null" body="relatable fact: carrots are not all orange" sub_id="-1" readable_date="Sep 01, 2019 07:50:09 AM" contact_name="Mr. Z" />
</r>'''

root = ET.fromstring(xml)
for sms in root.findall('sms'):
  print(f'{sms.attrib["address"]} {sms.attrib["readable_date"]}')
```

output

```
555555555 Aug 30, 2019 11:10:09 PM
6666666666 Aug 30, 2019 11:10:09 PM
7777777777 Sep 01, 2019 07:50:09 AM
```